# Find's -true option: what for?

Tags: linux, shell, find

GNU find (and others?) has a `-true` test along with the normal `-name`, `-mode`, `-user` and so on. From the man page:

> -true  Always true.

Every time I see the man page I notice this and wonder when it'd be useful. So, give me some examples of when it's useful :~)

Answer (score 5):

Might useful for debuging when you are ANDing or ORing statements.  So if you have a long command with a complex chain of arguments with lots of AND / OR between the statements, and something that isn't working like you expect, you could replace parts of it with -true to check your logic.

However, I am not sure if this is *why* it is there, but seems like a legitimate use.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to list all files in `find` format to pipe into another program ?

I guess it must be more efficient than using `-name "*"` or something similar.

Comment: `find` with no arguments at all does that.

Comment: Sure, but it's more explicit and has the same syntax with `-true`

Comment: How         so?

Answer (score 1):

Consider `find -delete -o -true -print`.
It's not too useful, but it's a pointer that you can think of `-true` or `-false` as means to override an in-expression result of some command with side effects.